# The principle of operation of second url argument when linking via <a> tag in django template

Tags: django-views, django-templates, django-urls

Here is my function that displays the entry or renders an error page in case the entry doesn't exist:

```
def entry(request, title):
    if title not in util.list_entries():
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html", {
            "error": "Page Not Found",
            "query": title
        })
    else:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {
            "entry": markdown2.markdown(util.get_entry(title)),
            "title": title
        })
```

This is the path:

```
path("wiki/<str:title>", views.entry, name="entry")
```

And here my template with a link to the entry page:

```
{% block body %}
    <h1>All Pages</h1>

    <ul>
        {% for entry in entries %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'entry' entry %}"> {{ entry }} </a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endblock %}
```

For better understanding, I would like to know how the second argument (entry) of the URL (`<a href="{% url 'entry' entry %}">`) in the template  works. Will it pass into the path (where `<str:title>`) first, or to the function's second argument (to the `title` in `def entry(request, title)`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand correctly, such second arguments in url (in my case this is the *entry*) are always context related (related to the context of the `entry` function `"entry": markdown2.markdown(util.get_entry(title))`). In the above HTML template, the first argument of url (first *entry* in `<a href="{% url 'entry' entry %}">`) tells to find the name "entry" in `path("wiki/<str:title>", views.entry, name="entry")`. After finding it, this path will link to the function's `views.entry` here for further operations inside the function. As you see, this path (this route) is expecting an additional value `<str:title>`. The second *entry* argument in url tells to pass the value of **entry** in the context dictionary to `<str:title>`. And the entry page appears.